# Does an empty vector occupy as much space as a pointer to a type that is currently set to nullptr?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a class:

```
class Foo{

std::vector<Sprite*> vec;
Sprite* bar = nullptr;

}
```

I then do:

```
Foo zoom;
```

At this point in program execution, which occupies more space ? vec or bar ?

EDIT:

In the following situation, if I do: `Foo zoom;` Which would occupy less space:

```
class Foo{
Sprite* bar1 = nullptr;
Sprite* bar2 = nullptr;
Sprite* bar3 = nullptr;
}
```

or

```
class Foo{
    std::vector<Sprite*> vec;
}
```

Comment: A vector obviously needs to hold a member for the size, the capacity and/or any other thing necessary to the implementation. It's not defined by the Standard.

Comment: `sizeof(vec)`...

Comment: So suppose I needed to keep track of a finite number of Sprite* , which may be 0 to some maximum number, would I be better of using a vector, or just making a number of Sprite* set to nullptr initially...

Comment: This all depends. If you have a maximum number and it's relatively small, you might keep it in a std::array or a C array. Then if the number of elements is too flexible, just use vector. Measure with both and decide based on the results you get. There is no way to tell what to do for every case.

Comment: @DeiDei But in the case of the array, again it should use atleast as much memory as the vector right ?

Comment: @KaizerSozay A plain array will use the least memory, as (once again) vector needs to hold size, capacity, etc. An extra 8-16 bytes will not kill your application. I don't see it mattering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this code:

```
class Foo{

    std::vector<Sprite*> vec;
    Sprite* bar = nullptr;

};
```

`bar` will be the size of a pointer, which is platform-dependent. Often, it will be either 32 bits (4 bytes) or 64 bits (8 bytes).

`vec` will be the size of a `std::vector` object, which is dependent on how your standard library has been implemented.

So we can't really say with *absolute* certainty, but we can make a pretty good guess based on what `std::vector` is required to do by the standard that an object of that type will be larger than a single pointer.

How much larger? Hard to say. Will it matter? No.

Resist the urge to try and build your own `std::vector` by declaring an array of pointers<sup>*</sup>. You will not outsmart the compiler. You'll end up with code that is both larger and slower than if you'd used the standard library's classes. That's what they are there for.

__
<sub><sup>*</sup> Unless your memory profiler is actually telling you that there is a problem here.</sub>

Comment: This is the kind of answer I'm looking for - so I guess what you're saying is, even if I have ten Sprite* variables, at most I would just be using ten x (size of a pointer on that platform), IF all of them are set to nullptr. Obviously once there is an actual object they will use more memory...

Comment: Having them set to `nullptr` makes absolutely no difference. A pointer is the same size whether it is set to a valid address or an invalid address.

Comment: Right - I meant the pointer won't use up any more memory than when it is set to null ptr, but the object it is pointing to will...

Answer (score 2):

The standard makes no guarantees.  In practise, the vector object must contain a pointer to the dynamically allocated memory and then something to say how much of that dynamic memory is in use, and how much is allocated.

Those *somethings* could either be pointers or counts.  In practise the memory consumption of either will be the same.

Thus typically, `sizeof(vec) == 3*sizeof(bar)`.

A vector with a small buffer optimization (where "small" vectors are allocated directly in the object), might be bigger.

Answer (score 2):

Both size of a pointer and size of a `std::vector` are not defined by the standard, so you need to figure out these numbers yourself on your target platform.

To get the size of a pointer to class, you need to write

```
sizeof(Spirit*)
```

Or create a new pointer and get its `sizeof`.

With `std::vector` the situation is a bit more complicated as some of the memory in it is allocated on stack (to store the information about the `std::vector` itself, like pointer to the data, or maybe its size), and some is allocated on heap (the data itself). To get the total amount of memory `std::vector` uses, you need to sum both of these values:

```
std::vector<Spirit*> vs;
sizeof(vs) + vs.capacity() * sizeof(Spirit*)
```

On my particular computer and compiler (x64, MSVC++ 2015) total amount of memory an empty `std::vector` uses is 24 bytes. **Please note that on your target platform the value may or may not be different**.